# Dynamic CheckBox and ComboBox

Tags: java, dynamic, checkbox, combobox

I have at problem with dynamic checkboxes. I want a combobox to show beside the checbox/checkboxes when one or more is selected. But I only get one combobox, which moves around whenever I select a new checkbox. So can anybody helpe me by telling me whats wrong and how I get more than one combobox?

```
for(int i = 0; i < names.length; i++) {
        // ParameterField
        JTextField fieldParam = new JTextField();
        fieldParam.setText(names[i]);
        fieldParam.setEditable(false);
        addElement(contentPanel, fieldParam, 25, yPos, 100, 20);

        // ValueField
        JTextField fieldValue = new JTextField();
        fieldValue.setText("" + values[i]);
        fieldValue.setEditable(false);
        addElement(contentPanel, fieldValue, 160, yPos, 100, 20);

        //RadioButtonField          
        final JCheckBox checkboxes = new JCheckBox();
        checkboxes.setActionCommand(names[i]);
        checkboxes.addActionListener(this);
        addElement(contentPanel, checkboxes, 325, yPos, 100, 20);


        final int checkBoxIndex = i;
        checkboxes.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae2) {
                if (checkboxes.isSelected()) {
                    comboProcent.setEnabled(true);
                    comboProcent.setModel(new javax.swing.DefaultComboBoxModel(new String[]{"2%", "5%", "10%"}));
                    addElement(contentPanel, comboProcent, 435, 50 + checkBoxIndex * 25, 80, 20);

                    setVisible(true);

                }

                    if (!checkboxes.isSelected()) {
                    contentPanel.remove(comboProcent);

                }

                System.out.println("checkbox is: " + checkBoxIndex);
            }
        });

        yPos = yPos + 25;
    }
```

Comment: It seems like a layout issue. In these cases you will have to put spaces in between and try out the various combinations so that the combo box does not move when a new layout is created, like in your code.

Comment: Out of curiosity, what object does "addElement" belong to in this?

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a new combo box instance for each checkbox. The best way I think would be to change their visibility based on when the checkboxes' values have changed. (I've done it this way before)

Comment: How can I create combo box instances for each checkbox, when my checkboxes are dynamic and I don't know how many there will be?

Comment: the code for addElement ` private void addElement(Container c, Component element, int x, int y, int h, int w) {
        element.setBounds(x, y, h, w);
        c.add(element);
    }`

Comment: You will find out when you know how many checkboxes there are.

Answer (score 0):

i dont know if i understood correctly but you should implement your own ComboBoxModel if you want a dinamyc combobox.

Comment: I can see that ComboBoxModel is an interface, but I'm new in Java so can you explain to me how this will solve the problem?

Comment: here is a good example, http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0240__Swing/JComboBoxUsingtheCustomModel.htm